# jquery hide element not working

Tags: jquery

I searched SO for a fix for this, found it, but my implementation seems flawed. Any clues?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#updt').ajaxForm(function(data) {
            if (data==1){
                $('#success').fadeIn("slow");
                $('#updt').resetForm();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#success").hide('blind', {}, 500)
                    }, 5000);

            }
            else if (data==2){
                $('#badserver').fadeIn("slow");
            }
            else if (data==3)
            {
                $('#bademail').fadeIn("slow");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: The goal BTW is to get the #success element to hide after 5 seconds

Comment: I assume you've got the jQuery UI framework loaded? (you're using "blind")

Comment: What is ajaxForm? It isn't part of jQuery.
What exacly isn't working?
Can you post HTML as well, at least the elements you reference?

Comment: Have you tracked what the value of "data" is before performing the conditional logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hide('blind', ..) try hide() - if this works, problem is, that you didn't load library with 'blind' hiding effect. (jQuery UI?)

Comment: Yeah, this worked. Didnt include jquery UI, made your change and it works. Is there a fade out or something similar thats built into jquery?